# STL map declaration in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

In a programming problem solution I got:

```
map<int,int>mp[200010];
```

Now can u please explain what does mp[200010] mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an array of `200010` maps, where each element of the array is a `map<int,int>`. `mp` is the name of the variable.

Comment: Okay. But if i say mp[2][3], what this mean now according to the array of maps declaration?

Comment: It means you want to look at the third map in your array (element `[2]`), and from that map you want to find the value associated with the key `3`.

Comment: @2013 An array of arrays (aka two-dimensional array) of maps.

Comment: Why would you ever need 200,000 maps? Something's funny.